# Django how to list customers in the sidebar

Tags: python, django

I created a system with Django. A user has several customers. The sidebar is in the `base.html` file. I created a view for the sidebar but It is working only in `homepage`. When I open a different page, it dissapears. How can I fix it?

**views.py**

```
def base(request):
    current_user = request.user
    userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=current_user)
    customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(companyName=userP[0].comp_name)
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'customer_list': customer_list})
```

**base.html**

```
<ul>
          <li class="header-menu">
            <span>Customers</span>
          </li>

          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
              {% for customer in customer_list %}
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
              <span>{{customer.name}}</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/customers/{{ customer.id }}/update"> Update</a>

                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Analyses</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
              {% endfor %}
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: You must provide an example of this "not working other page" , cause that's basically the essense of your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags). Django has template tags to perform complex operations in the templates.

What you can do is create a custom template tag which will take the user as the input and will return the queryset of customers, which you can save in a variable and then loop through it to display all the customers.

In myprojectdir/app_name/templatetags/customer_list.py

```
    from django import template
    from myapp.models import Customer

    register = template.Library()

    @register.simple_tag
    def get_customers(user):
        userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=user)
        customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(companyName=userP[0].comp_name)
        return customer_list
```

Then inside your template you can do this

```
{% load customer_list %}

{% get_customers request.user as customers %}

{% for customer in customers %}
   <Your html code>
{% endfor %}
```

Since Django passes the `request` in the context to all the templates automatically, you should access the current user using `request.user`.

For understanding where to create the template tag file, refer to this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

For more information on template tags refer to this:

You can also use [Inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) rather than simple tag for more flexibility and code reusability.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `{{ user }}` is the the current user in the template. You can use [reverse relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/) to get the companies like this:

```
{% for customer in user.userprofile.customer_set.all %}
     {{customer.name}}
{% enfor %}
```

**Explanation:** Suppose user has OneToOne relation with `UserProfile`, then you should get userprofile information by `user.userprofile`. Now, `Customer` has a ForeignKey to `UserProfile`. So, you can get all the `Customer`s by querying(or reverse querying) `user.userprofile.customer_set.all()`. If you have defined [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in ForeignKey, then the query should be  `user.userprofile.<related_name>.all()`